# Quickly creating a reference arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I often run into this situation:

```
foreach ($someObjects as &$someObject)
{
  $someObjectsIndex[$someObject->id] = $someObject;
}
```

And this:

```
$thingsIActuallyWant = [];
foreach ($associativeList as &$associativeItem)
{
  $thingsIActuallyWant[] = $associativeItem['id'];
}
```

I was wondering if there is an existing method or something to write these things shorter, without writing the foreach loop.

Comment: What is wrong with that?

Comment: [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to return you an array of just the elements you want.

For the 2nd example:

```
$thingsIActuallyWant = array_map(function($a){
    return $a['id'];
}, $associativeList);
```

As for the 1st, I suggest using the `foreach` as you have, because any alternative is going to be an ugly mess of [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine).

Comment: Thanks! I looked around and found that array_map is slower than foreach though :/

Comment: @RLV: Yeah, it can be.  Your `foreach`es are fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might try writing a function yourself, something like this:

```
function pluck($arr, $key)
{
    $tbr = array();

    foreach ($arr as $val)
    {
        if (is_array($val) && isset($val[$key]))
        {
            $tbr []= $val[$key];
        }
        elseif (is_object($val) && isset($val->$key))
        {
            $tbr [] = $val->$key;
        }
    }

    return $tbr;    
}
```

Then you could just call it:

```
$thingsIActuallyWant = pluck($associativeList, 'id');
```

Additionally, you should avoid passing variables by reference to foreach loops unless you need to.